# How to use C++ enums with UnitTest++ checks?

Tags: c++, enums, unittest++

I have the following enum:

```
namespace Country {
    enum {
        ITALY = 1,
        SPAIN = 2
    };
}
```

And the following UnitTest++ test:

```
TEST(something) {
    CHECK_EQUAL(Country::SPAIN, object.getCountry(1)); // getCountry returns int
}
```

This doesn't work. I thought `Country::SPAIN` would be automatically converted to int 2, but instead I get this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘CheckEqual(UnitTest::TestResults&, Country::<anonymous enum>, int, UnitTest::TestDetails)’
```

Comment: Is there a problem with casting `Country::SPAIN` to an `int` yourself?

Comment: No, it actually works. I didn't think about it (I'm new to C++). Thanks. Anyway, is there an explanation on why I can't to that, but I can do `int c = Country::SPAIN`?

Comment: `int c = Country::SPAIN` performs an implicit conversion. I've not used UnitTest++, so I don't know the actual signature of `CheckEqual`, but I suspect it's a template.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the enum to `int` yourself:

```
TEST(something) {
    CHECK_EQUAL(static_cast<int>(Country::SPAIN), object.getCountry(1));
}
```